# the following claim true or false: $\bigtriangledown f(x)$ always points in the same direction as $x-\hat{x}$ if $f(\hat{x})=0$

Tags: functions, vector-analysis

Take $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f\geq0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
A statement in an exercise claims the following:

given an $x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $\hat{x}$ be the point closest to $x'$ satisfying $f(\hat{x})=0.$ if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then the gradient $\bigtriangledown f(\hat{x})$ always points in the same direction as $x' - \hat{x}$.

This appears wrong to me as if $f \geq 0\ \forall x$, then $\bigtriangledown f(\hat{x}) = 0$. And even if we removed the condition $f \geq 0 \ \forall x$, taking $n=1, f=x$ with $x'=-1$ and $\hat{x}=0$ is a simple counter example. Am I missing something?

Comment: Terrible title.  Absolutely terrible and uninformative.  Change it.

Comment: What they have in mind is a Lagrange multipliers exercise, provided one assumes $\nabla f(\hat x)\ne 0$. And "points in the same direction" should be interpreted as being a scalar multiple of ... I have no idea what the hypothesis $f\ge 0$ is supposed to do ...

Comment: Ah...good call, Ted. This makes lots more sense. There's just a missing nabla on the first equality. I wonder fi my interpretation of "same direction" as "same half-space" might actually be what they're aiming at. Regardless, it's just a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, and your counterexamples show it. The claim in the exercise is false.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the claim might be a typo, and that it's talking about $\nabla (x')$ instead of $\nabla f (\hat{x})$. And "point in the same direction" is clearly false if taken literally, but suppose instead it meant "lie in the same half-space" (i.e., have positive dot product).

Even so, you'd need more conditions on $f$ to make this true. I might suggest throwing out that text.